# Using Xcode as EDITOR environment variable or opening a specific file in Xcode from the command line

Tags: xcode, command-line

I would like to open files in Xcode, which I use to develop, also in my conflict resolution process using `git-mediate -e`. Is there a command line command which I can set in the `EDITOR` enviroment variable that will invoke Xcode to edit a given file? (bonus: also in the specified line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to open a specific file in Xcode from the command line, use `open -a /Applications/Xcode.app`

For example:

```
open -a /Applications/Xcode.app your_file_name.txt
```

For being able to use as `EDITOR`, wrap this in a script `xcode-edit.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
open -a /Applications/Xcode.app $@
```

Now, you can use `EDITOR=xcode-edit.sh git-mediate -e`

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer, and I hope you don't mind that I also edited it to add instructions for using as EDITOR as I asked.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you have installed Xcode's command line tools, you have `xed`

```bash
% which xed
/usr/bin/xed
% xed --help
Options:
    -c, --create           Create the files if they do not exist.
    -p, --project <path>   Open the project, workspace, or package at <path> before opening the requsted files.
    -w, --wait             Wait for file to be closed by Xcode before terminating xed.
    -l, --line <number>    Select line <number> after opening file.
    -b, --background       Leave Xcode in the background (don't activate it).
    -h, --help             Show this information.
    -v, --version          Print version information.
```

So the following is what you want

```
export EDITOR="xed -w"
```